# Changing style for global-whitespace-mode not taking effect

Tags: whitespace-mode

Have written this function to change the style for `global-whitespace-mode`.  I describe the problem as follows.  Suppose one calls `(space-glow "tab-trail")` followed by `(space-glow "allvis")`.  But trying to do `(space-glow "tab-trail")` again, the style does not take effect.

```
(defun space-glow (form)
  "Global visualisation of tabs and trailing spaces."
  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ( (cseq '("allvis" "tab-trail" "disable")) )
      (completing-read " Space_glow: " cseq nil t "tab-trail"))))
  
  (require 'whitespace)

  (pcase form
    ("tab-trail"
     (setq whitespace-style '(face tab-mark tabs trailing))
     (global-whitespace-mode 1))
    ("allvis"
     (setq whitespace-style '(face tabs spaces trailing lines
            space-before-tab newline indentation empty
            space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark newline-mark))
     (global-whitespace-mode 1))
    ("disable"
     (global-whitespace-mode 0))) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle the mode to have a new style take effect.

Here I just unconditionally turned off the mode to start with. You can simplify the code for the "disable" case accordingly, if you like.

```lisp
(defun space-glow (form)
  "Global visualisation of tabs and trailing spaces."
  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ( (cseq '("allvis" "tab-trail" "disable")) )
      (completing-read " Space_glow: " cseq nil t "tab-trail"))))
  (require 'whitespace)
  (global-whitespace-mode 0) ; <========= Turn it off first.
  (pcase form
    ("tab-trail"
     (setq whitespace-style '(face tab-mark tabs trailing))
     (global-whitespace-mode 1))
    ("allvis"
     (setq whitespace-style
       '(face tabs spaces trailing lines
          space-before-tab newline indentation empty
          space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark newline-mark))
     (global-whitespace-mode 1))
    ("disable"
     (global-whitespace-mode 0))) )
```

Comment: Is it safe to call `(global-whitespace-mode 0)` when a mode might not be available?  `whitespace-mode` is a mode that is automatically available in emacs, correct?

Comment: I don't understand your comment question. I put that after your `require`.

Comment: I understand the fix now.  Because `require` imports (loads) the appropriate functionalities, then the value for `whitespace-style` can be set and used by the feature that uses it.  Is it customary to require disabling a mode to reset a customisation variable?  Are there packages that react dynamically to changes, and would it be the preferred behaviour?

Comment: If depends on what setting the option does and what enabling the mode does. In this case, just changing the variable value without toggling the mode didn't do what you wanted.